# Issue with Select Statement for MySQLdb Python

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy, mysql-python

I need to process the output of scrapy and store it to mysql using mysqldb. The below code works fine for article table however i need to access the category_id to insert in articlecategory table as foreign key. The item['channel'] is a list with categories.
However, the below output only returns id :1 which doesnt exit.

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    try:
        self.cursor.execute(\
            "insert into article (url, pid , date)\
            values (%s, %s, %s)",
            (item['url'], item['pid'], item['pub_date'])
            )
        article_id = self.cursor.lastrowid           
        self.conn.commit()

        for channel in item['channels']:
            self.cursor.execute("insert ignore into category(category_name) values(%s)",([channel]))                
            self.conn.commit()          

            category_id = self.cursor.execute("select id from category where category_name = %s", ([channel]))
            with open("cat.txt", "a") as f:
                f.write("id: %s \n" %  (category_id))
```

How can I access the id of category matching the category name? The syntax is working for insert operation with category table.

Comment: You have your entire thing in a `try` block with an `execute` statement that is invalid - you don't have values to fill the six `%s` tokens.  That may raise an exception and cause your entire block of code to not execute.

Comment: everything works fine, i need to get the category_id matching the category_name

Comment: Check that you got the columns name correct, without your table schema, data inside your table and more complete code I can't see what's clearly wrong.  Dump the key parts of the tables using a MySQL consoles to that database will point you to what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue,  had to do fetchall()

```
self.cursor.execute("select id from category where category_name = %s", ([channel]))
            category_id = self.cursor.fetchall()
            with open("cat.txt", "a") as f:
                f.write("id: %s \n" %  (category_id[0]))
```